# How to read in a CSV file in R without the quotation marks?

Tags: r, csv

All the values except in my .csv file except for one column called *year* are surrounded by three double-quotation marks. When I read in the file in RStudio using `read.csv2`, all values (including the column names) still got double-quotation marks (one before and after) around them. How do I switch off this behavior?

Here's an example with the column names and the first row.

```
"""Title""";"""Author""";"""year""";"""doi""";"""query_title"""
"""This is a title""";"""Smith""";2002;"""12345""";"""Another Title"""
```

Comment: What does the text look like in a text editor?

Comment: Good suggestion. When you look at the text in the editor, each value is surround by three double-quotation marks (three on the left, three on the right).

Comment: read.csv2 used `quote = "\""` as default. if you have three `"`, you need to add 2 more

Comment: I updated my question. I tried to use quote with `quote="\"'\"'\"'"` but it does not work.

Comment: If it were me, I'd open the .csv file in Excel. Use search and replace to remove the visible quotes, and save the adjusted file as a .csv file

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove them afterwards:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("yourFile.csv")

removeQuotes <- function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)

df <- df %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, removeQuotes)
```